# Pullback stable regular epimorphisms are preserved in full bireflective replete subcategories

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a bicomplete category, $\mathcal{A}$ a full replete bireflective subcategory of $\mathcal{B}$ and $f: A \longrightarrow A'$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{A}$.

1. Suppose that $f$ is a regular epimorphism in $\mathcal{B}$. Is it true that $f$ is also a regular epimorphism in $\mathcal{A}$?

I think yes, by the following proof: it is clear that $f$ is an epimorphism in $\mathcal{A}$ because $\mathcal{A}$ is full in $\mathcal{B}$. Thus, we must prove that $f$ is regular in $\mathcal{A}$.

Since $f$ is regular in $\mathcal{B}$, there exist two morphisms $g,h: B \longrightarrow A$ in $\mathcal{B}$ whose coequalizer agrees with $f$. Denote by $r_B:B \longrightarrow \overline{A}$ the $\mathcal{A}$-reflection of $B$. Then there exist $\overline{g},\overline{h}: \overline{A} \longrightarrow A$ such that $g=\overline{g} \circ r$ and $h=\overline{h} \circ r$. Using the assumption that $r_B$ is a bimorphism, one easily shows that $f$ is coequalizer of $\overline{g},\overline{h}$. This means that $f$ is a coequalizer in $\mathcal{A}$.

P.S. The previous claim without assuming repleteness!

2. Suppose that $f$ is a pullback stable regular epimorphism in $\mathcal{B}$. Is $f$ also pullback stable in $\mathcal{A}$? I have no clue.

Comment: Repleteness is usually irrelevant, so you don't need to worry about it. To answer your questions: 1. yes 2. yes.

Comment: So, my first argument is correct? Moreover, is it possible to have a proof of the second claim?

Comment: I don't know. At any rate it is not how I would prove it. (I would use the fact that when every morphism has a kernel pair, then every regular epimorphism is effective, and being an effective regular epimorphism is a property that is reflected by any conservative functor that creates kernel pairs and coequalisers. A similar kind of argument can be used for pullback-stable effective regular epimorphisms.)